# Sending a text from non-default texting application in airplane mode

Tags: android, android-contentresolver, smsmanager

I'm providing the ability to send and receive texts in my application - but have no intention of becoming the default texting application.

API 19+ only - so android automatically takes care of adding to the device content provider.

However, when the phone fails to send (lack of signal, airplane mode, etc.), the text will still show up in other apps as "failed" or even without the fail icon.

**How do I prevent "failed texts" from being sent to the content provider?**

Preferably I wouldn't have to check for airplane mode + cellular state, and rather just listen for the result of the text send request.

I send texts:

```
try {
        SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();

        ArrayList<String> divided = smsManager.divideMessage(text);
        ArrayList<PendingIntent> sentIntents = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < divided.size(); i++) {
            sentIntents.add(sentPendingIntent);
        }

        smsManager.sendMultipartTextMessage(address, null, divided, sentIntents, null);
        Log.i(TAG, "SMS sent");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.i(TAG, "SMS failed");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

I listen for success/failure through registered broadcast receiver:

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    switch (getResultCode()) {
        case Activity.RESULT_OK:
                    Toast.makeText(context, "SMS sent successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            break;
        case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_GENERIC_FAILURE:
                    Toast.makeText(context, "Generic failure cause", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            break;
        case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_NO_SERVICE:
                    Toast.makeText(context, "Service is currently unavailable", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            break;
        case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_NULL_PDU:
                    Toast.makeText(context, "No pdu provided", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            break;
        case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_RADIO_OFF:
                    Toast.makeText(context, "Radio was explicitly turned off", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: "How do I prevent 'failed texts' from being sent to the content provider?" - If you're not the default messaging app, you can't, really.

Comment: That seems like an oversight :/ so I suppose I should just check for cellular/airplane as the solution

Comment: Eh, probably not oversight, but just in keeping with their increasing restrictions on non-default apps. In KitKat, they removed the write ability for non-defaults, and intentionally had the system keep track of their sent messages, likely to curb abuse by apps that were sending SMS without notifying the user. In Marshmallow, it got even more restrictive, in that non-defaults can't even read failed messages. They can only get the sent and inbox. Just one more thing to make it harder to abuse or somehow exploit SMS. Methinks they just want the user to be able to be aware of what's going on.